# Unable to get child value on newtonsoft.Json.LinqJvalue when reading coinbase api?

Tags: c#, json.net, coinbase-api

Hello I am trying to get the coinbase API exchange rates from the URL however json.net does not seem to be able to format the JSON file to read the children
[image]

this is the method that throws the error

```
public string CalculateCoinValue(Coinbase connector)
{
    //bool valid = connector.rates.isValid;

    string cryptoExchangeRate;

    if (connector.rates != null)
    {
        cryptoExchangeRate = (string)connector.rates["data"]["currency"]["rates"][Settings.defualtCrypto.ToUpper()];

    }

    return "";
}
```

this is the method im using to get the JSON data which stores it in a JObject whithin the Coinbase class

```
public async Task<JObject> GetExchangeRatesAsync()
{

    HttpClient webClient = new HttpClient();
    string url = string.Format("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=" + Settings.defaultCurrency);
    HttpResponseMessage coinbaseJsonRaw = await webClient.GetAsync(url);
    return JObject.Parse(await coinbaseJsonRaw.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

what am I doing wrong for this not to work?

Comment: remove ["currency"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json returned looks different. try the below

```
cryptoExchangeRate = (string)connector["data"]["rates"][Settings.defualtCrypto.ToUpper()];
```